# MySql statement - enclosing variables

Tags: mysql

How do I make this statement correct:

```
$sel= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$em' and password='AES_ENCRYPT("'$psw'","'SecretKey'")'";
```

I keep getting a parse error of an unexpected T_VARIABLE. Is it the quote marks enclosing the variables in the password section of the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
$sel= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$em' and password=AES_ENCRYPT('$psw','SecretKey')";
```

`AES_ENCRYPT` is a MySQL function, so no need to add quotes, just the variables.

Answer (score 1):

update like this

```
$sel= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$em' and password = AES_ENCRYPT('$psw', 'SecretKey')";
```